# how to find closest tr on condition of button is clicked or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to find closest tr based on condition whether  buttun is clicked or not in that td and based on that i will bind a dropdown element.
My design is dynamically generated.

```
let newRowContent = "<tr>"
                     +"<td> <select name='upclist' class='form-control' id='upcList" + i +"'><option selected='selected'>Select</option></select></td>"
 + "<td><input id='tdesc" + i +"' type='number' class='form-control' /></td>"
                                     + "<td><input id='tamnt" + i +"' type='number' class='form-control' /></td>"
                                     +"<td><input id='trem" + i +"' type='number' class='form-control' /></td>"
                                     +"<td><input type='button' style='margin-left:2%;' value='Add' id='abc' name='grdbtn'  class='btnrowvalue3' onclick='insRow()' /></td>"
                                     + "</tr>";
                $("#ipcelltbll tbody").append(newRowContent);
```

trying to append value in dropdown based on condition which row button is clicked then dropdown of that row will be append based on closest condition don't know whether syntax is correct or not.

```
var tr = $('input[name="grdbtn"]:click').closest('tr');
tr.find('select[name="upclist"]').append(opt);
```

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no `:click`

Comment: @epascarello what would be exact syntax to if button is clicked then find it's closest tr..

Comment: There is no syntax for that. You would need to bind an event for clicks and store it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly you want. Seems like you want to listen to a click event and alter a select. Basic idea with event delegation.

```
$("#yourTable tbody").on("click", "button", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  var select = row.find("select");
  console.log(select);
});
```